# Apache POI Word Styles How do I get rid of gaps?

Tags: java

Apache POI Word

table, text, enter, etc. How do I get rid of gaps in everything?

Can I do it like no spacing in word style?

Apache POI Word

table, text, enter, etc. How do I get rid of gaps in everything?

I want to do it like TO

[image]

```
public class PoiTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();

        XWPFTableRow row1 = table.getRow(0);
        row1.getCell(0).setText("First Row, First Column");
        row1.addNewTableCell().setText("First Row, Second Column");

        row1 = table.createRow();
        row1.getCell(0).setText("Second Row, First Column");
        row1.getCell(1).setText("Second Row, Second Column");

        row1 = table.createRow();
        row1.getCell(0).setText("Third Row, First Column");
        row1.getCell(1).setText("Third Row, Second Column");

        XWPFParagraph title = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun titleRun = title.createRun();
        titleRun.setText("First");

        title = doc.createParagraph();
        titleRun = title.createRun();

        titleRun.setText("Second");
        
        
        FileOutputStream out;
        
        try {

            out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test\\test.docx");
            doc.write(out);

            System.out.println("ok!!!");
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad news (or... possibly good news). When running your code as-is, it looks just fine:

[image]

Inside the running code, the result of `System.getProperty("java.version")` is `11.0.16` (although Eclipse claims I am using OpenJDK 17.0.4)

Resulting `.docx` file was opened with LibreOffice 7.0.4.2 to get the above screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I've tested it in several places, but I'm still having problems.

Comment: XWPFParagraph title = doc.createParagraph();  title .setSpacingAfter(0); 


I searched it here and found it.
Thank you.